# jquery showing ALL DIVs in table, want to display only the div after the link

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

I can't figure out how to select the immediate div inside each td and load up the page.
Everylink toggles every single hidden div!

The table has 100s of rows.
Each row has a part that can be seen, which is a link.
And then i included a div that is hidden inside each row.
I just want the link on each row to display the immediate div below it , now every single one.

my html is set up like:

```
<div id=container>
<div id=box>
<table>
<tr><td><a href=link></a>
<div id=page class=hidden></div></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

and the jquery does this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("td a").click(function() {
  var myUrl = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#page").load(myUrl);
  $(this).toggle();
  return false;
});
$(".hidden").hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't see an <a> tag in your html

Comment: Did you try adding e.stopPropogation() (pass 'e' to the click handler)

Comment: Is this your actual HTML structure?

Comment: There's something wrong with your sample code.  It doesn't match up with what you are saying. There's no `<a>` tag in your html and if there was, clicking it would toggle it. Not a `<div>`

Comment: yea i forgot the <a></a> tag, the code is not actual code, just simplfied.

Answer (score 1):

Your code `$(this).toggle();` toggles visibility of the link, not the div following it.

Replace that line with `$(this).next('div').toggle();` and you should be fine.

Comment: this solves the showing/hideing, but not the loading problem. he's still got 100's of divs with the same id, which is going to cause all sorts of badness.

Comment: @Patricia He said it was a simplified version of the HTML; I took him at his word. But you're right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector

```
$('td > div.hidden') // to get the first div with the hidden class in td
```

Comment: it is still loading into the first #page div and expanding the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I not sure I'm following, would you mind editing your question to make it more specific?

Comment: you have more then one div with the id page?

Answer (score 0):

Elements have to have UNIQUE Id's, so, you'll have to use a class to identify your divs that repeat, and give them unque ids!

something like this should do the trick:

```
<div id=container>
    <div id=box>
        <table>
           <tr><td><a href=link></a>
                   <div id="page1"  class="hidden page"></div>
               </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td a").click(function(e) {
         $(".hidden").hide(); //hide all the divs at first.
          e.preventDefault(); //stop the link from being followed
          var myUrl = $(this).attr("href"); 
          $(this).siblings('div.page').load(myUrl).show();  //get the div and load it, then show it

          return false;
    });


});
```

Comment: oops fixed the typo of e.siblings.  hope that's what you were referring to about it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("td a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest("td").find("#page1").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: It just followed the link instead of loading into the div.

Comment: if you change it to `function(e)` and then add `e.preventDefault();` it should fix taht problem